# Is it possible to reuse a nock object?

Tags: node.js, nock

I am using nock for testing HTTP Endpoints and I don't want to define the headers and baseURL multiple times.
Is it problematic to do something like this?

```js
const serviceNock = nock('https://my-service.local')
  .matchHeader('Api-Key', 'my-api-key')
  .matchHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
```

Use serviceNock in test1

```js
const serviceNock1 = serviceNock
      .patch('/resources')
      .reply(200)
```

Use serviceNock in test2

```js
const serviceNock2 = serviceNock
      .patch('/resources')
      .reply(500)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea about the nock (never used it and don't know if chaining creates new object or just modify the existing one), but why not to do something like next:

```
const getBaseNockService = () => nock('https://my-service.local')
  .matchHeader('Api-Key', 'my-api-key')
  .matchHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')

const serviceNock1 = getBaseNockService()
      .patch('/resources')
      .reply(200)

const serviceNock2 = getBaseNockService()
      .patch('/resources')
      .reply(500)
```

Here we define factory function `getBaseNockService` and get full functionality you requested

Comment: You're right, that would definitely work! Thanks!